# Regular Expression: Having All strings except bba and abb

Tags: regex, automata

I was working on Regular Expression, There was a question about making a Regular Expression having string containing at-least one of among **bba** or **abb** but not both at the same time.

I made below expression for that.

> a*(baa*)*b+b*(a*ab)*a*

But, A question arise in my mind to make a regular expression having All strings excep **bba** and **abb**

I am confuse in it now.

Kindly help.

**Note: Its about Automata, Not JavaScript Or PHP Regex ........**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation with a positive and negative lookahead to assert that one of the variations is not there and that the other variation is and vice versa.

`^(?:(?=.*abb)(?!.*bba)|(?!.*abb)(?=.*bba)).*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF3nbF/1)

If neither of them could be there, you could use:

`^(?!.*(?:abb|bba)).*$`

Comment: Wouldn't  ^((?!bba)(?!abb).)*$   be enough?

Comment: @StephanT. That would not match when either of them is present.

Comment: @StephanT I see what you mean, for matching all strings excep bba and abb that would match indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an automata, wouldnt the answer just be

```
b(aa*b + a)* + (aa*b + a)* + b*         
// First one:  words like baaaaabaababab, baaa, babaaaaaa 
// Second one: words like aaaaabaababab, aaaaaa, aab
// Third one:  words like bbbbb, b, , bbb
```

because you can't type bb unless it is the only word in the regex

**a^+** means **at least one a** and can be replaced by **aa***

Comment: Close, you want it to be `b?(a^+b)* + b*` as the string can optionally start with a  single `b`.

Comment: Ouch, you are right, i will edit it immediately :D Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try regex `^(?!(.*abb.*bba|.*bba.*abb)).*$`

This will match the string contains either `abb` or `bba` not both

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jYpJ9r/1)